# Sed insert line multiple times on pattern

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have

```
/var/log/syslog
{
    rotate 7
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    compress
    postrotate
        invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
    endscript
}

/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages
{
    rotate 4
    weekly
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
    endscript
}
```

What I want to do is insert `olddir /var/log/oldlog` a line before the top `rotate 7` and lower `rotate 4` lines.
Is it possible to make `sed` do possible multiple insertions?
Also it also needs to ignore the `rotate >` pattern in the postrotate.

I thought I would ask before I try and do something longwinded and horrid.
Also the above is the main question but a secondary one would be to iterate all files in the directory with the above.

Any pointers would be really appreciated

Comment: I have commented my answer with additional notes, did it work?

Comment: If I have answered to your question, would you mind accepting my answer? Thanks!

Comment: It did apols I was away and many thanks. Well there is a mixture of conf file whitespace. Some using double space and some using tab.

the .bak is a great idea as can use tabooext + .bak in /etc/logrotate.conf so can merrily away with just the edits.
You would have 10 votes if it would allow :)
I really wish I could get my head round sed/grep... regex its always a stumbling block for me and a massive hole in my scripting.

Comment: You are welcome! `grep`, `sed`, `awk` and linux commands in general are powerful tools! On top of voting you can press on the green mark to accept my answer as correct and close this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Input:**

```
$ cat input_file
/var/log/syslog
{
    rotate 7
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    compress
    postrotate
        invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
    endscript
}

/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages
{
    rotate 4
    weekly
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
    endscript
}
```

**Command:**

```
sed -i.bak '/rotate [0-9]\+/{s@^\( \+\)@\1olddir /var/log/oldlog\n\1@}' input_file
```

**Output:**

```
$ cat input_file
/var/log/syslog
{
    olddir /var/log/oldlog
    rotate 7
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    compress
    postrotate
        invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
    endscript
}

/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages
{
    olddir /var/log/oldlog
    rotate 4
    weekly
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
    endscript
}
```

**Explanations:**

- `-i.bak` will activate the option to take a backup of each file before modifying them and add the suffix `.bak` at the end of each filename.
- `/rotate [0-9]\+/` will only take the lines that contain `rotate` followed by a space and an integer
- when `sed` encounters one of those lines, it will execute `s@^\( \+\)@\1olddir /var/log/oldlog\n\1@` which is a find and replace command that will replace the beginning of the line as well as all the spaces by the pattern. I have taken into account the spaces to keep the indentation by using back reference `\1`.

**2nd question:**

```
find /path/to/my/files -type f -exec sed -i.bak '/rotate [0-9]\+/{s@^\( \+\)@\1olddir /var/log/oldlog\n\1@}' {} \;
```

You might add `-name 'YOUR FILE PATTERN'` if you want to reduce the find scope. Also consider using `-maxdepth N` to  limit the depth in term of subdirs of the search

**Update:**

As the text contains a mix of `\t` and spaces, we can use the following POSIX class `[:blank:]` that will match those 2 characters.

**Command:**

```
sed -i.bak '/^[[:blank:]]*rotate[[:blank:]]\+[0-9]\+[[:blank:]]*$/{s@^\([[:blank:]]*\)@\1olddir /var/log/oldlog\n\1@}' input_file
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks I will play with that and see, great explanation.
I knew there would prob be a one liner but anything but the simplest regex just is up there with long haul flights when it comes to above my head.

Comment: Hey Allan I am running that and both files are not like yours? olddir /var/log/oldlog not there?
prob something to do with raspbian regex?
Just a copy as .bak file

Comment: @StuartNaylor: this might be because your files have some `tab` in them. Can you try to run `cat -vTE $file` and tell me if you have some `^I`

Comment: @StuartNaylor: You might have to change `s@^\( \+\)@` into `s@^\([ \t]\+\)@` and `rotate [0-9]\+` into `rotate[ \t]\+[0-9]\+`

Comment: Yeah its tab, I will check that out. What you did gives me the inkling to make a solution whilst before I was just looking blankly :)
Many thanks

olddir /var/log/oldlog$
^Irotate 7$
^Idaily$
^Imissingok$
^Inotifempty$
^Idelaycompress$
^Icompress$

Comment: @StuartNaylor: ok cool! Let me know if you manage to make it works

Comment: Perhaps with : /^[[:blank:]]*rotate[[:blank:]][0-9]\+[[:blank:]]$/ is better ?

Comment: @ctac_: thank you a lot for your remark, I have updated the command. ;-) Cheers

Comment: It's not only for space or tab. It is also for lines like 'ex rotate 7' or 'rotate 4 abc'.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: wow soon at 30k rep, super impressive! ;-) I wish I had more time to contribute to SO. But after changing jobs last year, I have been too busy to really be as active as before and I do miss it...

Comment: @Allan, same here buddy even I am not getting that much time(you can check my profile when you get time too :) ) but whenever I get come here to help and learn, good to see you buddy as always(trust me on this) :)